# Obtener HTML desde un servicio que vive en un componente en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un componente con esta estructura

```
collabs
 collabs.component.html
 collabs.component.ts
 collabs.component.module.ts
 collabs.component.service.ts
 collabs.helpbox.html
```

Por medio de un servicio necesito el HTML que contiene `collabs.helpbox.html`, este archivo tiene una línea de código sencillo

```
<p>Help Box works!</p>
```

Estoy tratando de obtener ese HTML por medio del servicio y este es el código

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CollabsService {

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getHelpBox(): Observable<string> {
    const url = './collabs.helpbox.html';
    return this._http.get( url, { responseType: 'text' } );
  }
}
```

Y ahora así lo uso en el `collabs.component.ts` lo tengo así

```
  constructor(
    private collab$: CollabsService
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.collab$.getHelpBox().subscribe( (html: string ) => console.log( html ) );
  }
```

Este HTML lo necesito por que lo enviaré como atributo de otro componente, este rendieriza HTML, pero tengo este error

> Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/collabs.helpbox.html:
> 404 Not Found

Pero estoy viendo que está buscando en la raíz del proyecto, no está respetando la ruta relativa. No quiero poner la ruta estática, puesto que pudiera cambiar hasta de dominio.

¿Qué me falta? ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: ese archivo html está añadido como si fuera parte del código. Por qué no añadirlo directamente en la plantilla `collabs.component.html`?

Comment: mmm no es parte de un parámetro que pienso pasar a un componente hijo.
`<child-component [html]="collabComponent"></child-component>` Algo así. O sea, cada componente padre, pasarle un HTML distinto al componente hijo.

Comment: Te da error por que esa ruta no la haz definido en ningún route. Hasta donde entiendo, debes registrar un componente para que sea renderizado en la vista. Cual es el objetivo de enviarlo por parámetro?